# Find all header files in direcotry and all subdirectories without external modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find all .h files in a diretory and its subdiretories.
But without install external modules.
I tried this:

```
import os

def find_h_in_folder(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".h"):
            print(file)
        elif os.path.isdir(file):
            find_h_in_folder(file)


find_h_in_folder("X:\folder")
```

But it doesen't work, because I think

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
```

only parses files and not directories?
So I can't access the subdirectories, but i don't know who to also parse the directories.

Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: Why not use bash script if it's one time job using `find` command?

Comment: you forgot to escape your backslash in `"X:\folder"`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but there are some more actions to do so thats why I want to use python

Comment: @Chase yes you are correct. Just Put in this path as example and forgot about this

Comment: Why do you think `os.listlir` excludes directories? It is very easy indeed to prove to yourself that it does not, in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

root = '/some/directory'
pattern = ".h"

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(pattern):
            print(os.path.join(path, name))
```

This walks through all subdirectories and finds `.h` files

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for....os.walk() is a great idea

Comment: That's probably a better approach, but doesn't explain why the OP's attempt failed.(Hint: you need to join the previous `path` in front of the new one when you recurse.)

Comment: @Loois95 we can do this via list comprehensions also but as you said there are other processing to be done, I did this without list comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account the **full path** of the directories for them to be processed by `os` functions.

When you iterate through `os.listdir`, each `file` is just the *name* of the file and/or directory. If you'd like to traverse said directory, you need to join the original path with file name.

```py
def find_h_in_folder(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".h"):
            print(file)
        elif os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, file)):
            find_h_in_folder(os.path.join(path, file))
```